# Solve equation with absolute value of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex numbers $z$ such that $|z| + \overline{z}=9-3i$.

Thinking about using with the fact that $z=a+bi$ and $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ in some way. Not sure how.

Comment: Hint: try comparing the complex and imaginary parts of the RHS and LHS, and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\;z=x+iy\;$ , so that your equation is

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x-iy=9-3i\stackrel{\text{compare real and imag. parts}}\implies\begin{cases}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x=9\\{}\\y=3\end{cases}\;\;\implies$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+3^2}+x=9\implies x^2+9=81-18x+x^2\implies18x=72\implies x=4$$

and the unique solution is $\;4+3i\;$

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{z}=-|z|+9-3i\,$, then taking the magnitudes of the two sides:

$$\require{cancel}
|z|^2=(-|z|+9)^2+3^2 \;\;\iff\;\; \cancel{|z|^2}=\cancel{|z|^2}-18 |z| +90 \;\;\iff\;\; |z|=5
$$

Substitute $|z|=5$ back into the given equation, then $\bar z = 4-3i \iff z = 4+3i\,$.